# "fatal error: unavailable function can't be called"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

So I just downloaded Xcode 7 GM, and out pops this error:

```
fatal error: unavailable function can't be called: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/RangeReplaceableCollectionType.swift, line 329
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does cleaning the project/removing all derived data help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had a protocol with the function `extend` as a requirement.

```
public protocol Appendable: Initiable, SequenceType
{
    mutating func insert(_: Generator.Element)
    mutating func append(_: Generator.Element)
    mutating func extend<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Generator.Element>(_: S)
}
```

Now `extend` has been renamed to `appendContentsOf`, however Xcode stayed shush when it came to my protocol requiring it (a bug). Whenever I called `extend` on conformant types (in my case `Array`, `Dictionary` and `Set`), instead of telling me that `extend` had been renamed, it just resolved the issue by using a function guaranteed by `Appendable`, also `extend`. And guess who provided the implementation.

That's right.

PS: I ran the migrator before doing all of this, and **it should have resolved this issue**, but eh.